# Non-ccc and non-locally ccc

Tags: ct.category-theory

What is an example of a category $\mathcal C$ which is not cartesian closed or locally cartesian closed, but for which there exist interesting examples of objects $X,Y \in \mathcal C$ such that an exponential object $Y^X$ exists?

Comment: The category of (small) semicategories also called non-unital categories (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semicategory) should answer your question (I am not sure to understand the end of your sentence).

Comment: Note that if a category with a terminal object is not cartesian-closed, it is also not locally cartesian-closed.

Comment: @varkor Good point. the category of general topological spaces is a much simpler example. A Hausdorff topological space is exponentiable if and only if it is locally compact.

Comment: The category of smooth manifolds. The category of classes and class functions.

Comment: @DavidRoberts And the category of diffeological spaces is cartesian closed. I am wondering whether diffeological spaces are a closure of some sort of the category of smooth manifolds ? I can't find the answer in the nLab. It is only explained why the inclusion functor is full and faithful.

Comment: I've just edited the question with a guess at what the mysterious clause "except x, of all x" might mean. It seems to align with the sorts of examples people were giving in the comments anyway.

Comment: @TimCampion Ah thanks: now I understand the question.

Comment: Another example: in any category with finite limits, if $1$ denotes the terminal object then $X^1$ always exists and is $X$. in an extensive category, if n denotes the coproduct of n-copies of $1$, then $X^n$ exists and is the usual cartesian power of $X$

Answer (score 1):

The category of topological spaces and continuous maps is like that, see for instance [Topologies on spaces of continuous functions](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Emhe/papers/newyork.pdf) by Martín Escardó and Reinhold Heckmann.